# FlaskSqlAlchemy multi join on multi table. ambiguous column name

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm about a month into learning and working with SQLAlchemy. I've been working on troubleshooting this for several hours using previous posts on StackOverflow and reading SQLAlchemy docs.  Even watched videos on Youtube.

Can anybody help me with creating a proper query?  I think I need to alias the column name, but I haven't got that to work yet.

Thank you in advance

```
cdm_mapping = db.Table('cdm_mapping',
                       db.Column('product_id', db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True),
                       db.Column('cdm_id', db.ForeignKey('CDM.id'), primary_key=True)
                       )

user_products = db.Table('user_products',
                         db.Column('user_id', db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
                         db.Column('product_id', db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
                         )

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    website = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    company = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    permission = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)

    products = db.relationship("Product", secondary=user_products, back_populates="users")

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    product_shortname = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=True)
    homepage = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    review_count = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    github = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(15000), nullable=True)
    logo_file = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')

    # Relationships
    categories = db.relationship("Category", secondary=product_category, back_populates="products")
    features = db.relationship("Feature", secondary=product_feature, back_populates="products")
    cdm_elements = db.relationship("CDM", secondary=cdm_mapping, back_populates="products")
    vendor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('vendor.id'), nullable=True)
    users = db.relationship("User", secondary=user_products, back_populates="products")


class CDM(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(15000), nullable=True)

    # Relationship
    products = db.relationship("Product", secondary=cdm_mapping, back_populates="cdm_elements")
```

This is the query I constructed dozens of different ways.

```
user_id = 1
def get_toolkit_in_cdm(user_id):
        query = db.session.query(CDM.name, Product.product_name, User.username).join(CDM.products).join(User.products).filter(User.id == user_id).all()
        for product, cdm, user in query:
            print(product, cdm, user)
```

I get this error.

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) ambiguous column name: product.product_name

Comment: The problem here is that you have two joins to the `products` table. So when you say `product_name`, the query doesn't know which of those two joins to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JOIN same table twice with aliases on SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550653/join-same-table-twice-with-aliases-on-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it looked like you had me going in the right direction, but it didn't work.  I created alias for User, Product and CDM.  It appears that it created an alias for them, but the error still shows because the column is in the association table.

Comment: Neither `User` nor `CDM` causes the issue here because the underlying tables are only joined once. The problem is with `join(Users.products)` and `join(CDM.products)` which joins the same table twice. You need the alias at this level as shown in the answer I linked. If you need further help, you will have to show what you tried.

Comment: I can alias Users.products or CDM.products, but that doesn't help because they are part of the association table.  Users.products.product_id and CDM.products.product_id.  I cant figure out how to alias the column of the association table column.  I also tried CDM.products.label("cdmprods") and Users.products.label("usrprods") but that presented a new error.

Comment: Oic... you have two many to many relationships. Do the need to be m2m? Have you considered other schemas? For the current problem, what happens when you alias or label `User.products` and `CDM.products`? Often a different error is a sign of progress.